# Allow a third party to access my Google Analytic account

Tags: google-analytics

As a webmaster I have my Google account which contains all of the Google Analytics used by the various sites I manage.

My question is can I give a third party (the site owner) access to one of the Google Analytics accounts without giving access to other Google Analytics accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can give users access to their own account without giving them access to your main account or other accounts under yours.

From [this guide](http://www.thesearchguru.com/google-analytics.asp):

1. Login to your Google Analytics account.
2. From the “Analytics Settings” page that you see when you first login, Click on “User Manager.”
3. On the “User Manager” screen, click on “Add User”.
4. On the “Create New User For Access”, enter the email address of the person you wish to grant access to.
5. Choose the level of access you wish to grant the person:

   - View reports only – This level of access allows a user to see the analytic information about your site, but does not allow them to change goals, add users or add websites.
   - Account Administrator – This level of access allows the user to see the analytic information about your site as well as making administrative change to your account, such as changing goals, adding users and adding websites. If you are adding The Search Guru, choose this level of access.
6. If you choose “View reports only” as the access level, under “Allow access to,” choose a website on the list (on the left); this is the site you’re granting the person the ability to access analytic information. Click on the “Add” button in the center of the screen. Repeat this process if you wish to grant access to more than one website.
7. Click on “Save changes.”